# Cosmos db Order by on 'computed field'

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to select data based on a status which is a string. What I want is that status 'draft' comes first, so I tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM c 
ORDER BY c.status = "draft" ? 0:1
```

I get an error:

> Unsupported ORDER BY clause. ORDER BY item expression could not be mapped to a document path

I checked Microsoft site and I see this:

> The ORDER BY clause requires that the indexing policy include an index for the fields being sorted. The Azure Cosmos DB query runtime supports sorting against a property name and not against computed properties.

Which I guess makes what I want to do impossible with queries... How could I achieve this? Using a stored procedure?

**Edit**:

About stored procedure: actually, I am just thinking about this, that would mean, I need to retrieve all data before ordering, that would be bad as I take max 100 value from my database... IS there any way I can do it so I don t have to retrieve all data first? Thanks

Thanks!

Comment: You'd need to store this value in a property. You can't do an inline computation like that.

Comment: Hi,does my answer helps you?If so,you could mark it for answer.Thank you.

Comment: Hello Jay, I asked you a question on my comment section (pls see edit section of my post), i wonder if using store proc will make me scan the whole database while i just want to order ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ORDER BY item expression could not be mapped to a document path.

Basically, [we are told](https://vincentlauzon.com/2017/11/06/a-few-cosmosdb-query-limitations/) we can only sort with properties of document, not derived values. `c.status = "draft" ? 0:1` is derived value.

My idea:

Two parts of query sql: The first one `select c.* from c where c.status ='draft'`,second one `select c.* from c where c.status <> 'draft' order by c.status`. Finally, combine them.

Or you could try to use stored procedure you mentioned in your question to process the data from the result of `select * from c order by c.status`. Put draft data in front of others by if-else condition.

Comment: Problem is that I have 4 possible values in my status column which affect the order  by, and i don t  want to do 4 queries ... I should try the store proc. Thanks

Comment: @Tom Ok,when you meet any issue with sp ,just post here and i will help you.

Comment: Jay, Actually, I am just thinking about this, that would mean, I need to retrieve all data before ordering, that would be bad as i take max 100 value from my database... IS tehre any way i can do it so  i don t have to retrieve all data first? Thanks!

Comment: @Tom - please don't start a discussion in comments, or ask additional questions under an answer. There's really no way to support this type of conversation in Stack Overflow.